# Can iOS Development Certificate and iOS Push Certificate Development

Tags: ios, certificate, push, csr

Can iOS Development Certificate and iOS Push Certificate Development use the same CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest when creating the certificates? Or they have to have different key pair on the keychain?

Comment: how can I download the CSR of the automatic certificate that Xcode generated so I can use it for the Push Certificate?